# Algoritmo de Newton-Raphson

Tags: c++, análise-numérica

considere o algoritmo de Newton-Raphson para calcular as raízes da equação f(x)=0
com  (0.5, 1 , 2 , 3.4556) para cada x inicial.

f(X)=X^4-12X^3+47x^2-60X
Fiz o código igual ao algoritmo, porem não esta encontrando as raízes, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>

float Abs( float x ){

  return x>=0? x:-x;
};

int main(){
  float xini = 0, xnovo , Fxnovo, Fdxnovo , E ;     
  int k = 0;

  printf( "Digite o x inicial: " );
  scanf( "%f", &xnovo );
  printf( "Digite a precisao: " );
  scanf( "%f", &E );

  do{

    xini = xnovo;
    Fxnovo = ( xini * xini * xini * xini ) - 12 * (xini * xini * xini) + 47*(xini * xini) - 60 * xini; //inserir sua função principal aqui
    Fdxnovo = 4. * ( xini * xini * xini) - 36. * (xini * xini ) + 94 * xini - 60; //inserir a derivada da função principal aqui
    xnovo = xini - ( Fxnovo / Fdxnovo );
    k += 1;
    printf( "\niteracao = %d", k );
    printf( "\nxini = %f\nxnovo = %f", xini, xnovo, Fxnovo, Fdxnovo );

  } while(Abs(Fxnovo) > E);

  printf( "\n\nxnovo - xini = %f\n", xnovo -(xini) );
  printf( "A solucao final e: %f\n", xnovo );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Que algoritmo de Newton-Raphsom é esse? Para cálculo aproximado das raízes por métodos numéricos?

Comment: Sim para calculo de raízes numéricas.

Comment: Sim para calculo de raízes numéricas

Comment: O algoritmo prevê que a variação de `x` é `-f(x)/f'(x)` por iteração? Não deveria saltar para o ponto onde a reta formada pela derivada daquele ponto intercepte o eixo `x`?

Comment: Se essa variação realmente vai para o ponto onde a reta encontra o eixo `x`, então me avise que não estou conseguindo demonstrar

Comment: Ok, vi que essa variação vai realmente achar o ponto da interseção da reta com o eixo `x`

Comment: sim a variação de x é por interação.

Comment: Você sabe definir funções em C? Se sim, podemos testar a validade do seu algoritmo com baixo custo. No lugar de por a resolução do polinômio e a resolução de sua função derivada diretamente, faça `Fxnovo = func(xini)` e `Fdxnovo = deriv(xini)`. Para testar se está tudo nos conformes, podemos testar com `func(x) = x^2 - x` (raízes 0 e 1) e `deriv(x) = 2 x - 1`. Começando com `x = 4`, deve convergir rapidamente para uma das raízes

Comment: ixi mano ainda não estudei funções não .

Comment: Bem, você usou a função a `Abs`. E ela não está retornando realmente o valor absoluto de um número positivo. Faça `Abs(4)`, seu resultado será `-4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está na definição de `Abs`. Atualmente, `Abs(4)` vai retornar `-4`. Então, basta encontrar o primeiro `f(x)` positivo que vai sair do laço.

A correção é a seguinte:

```
float Abs( float x ){
  return x >=0? x: -x;
}
```

Comment: Como é `float`, posso fazer uma brincadeira só com o bit de sinal, não precisando portanto de comparação alguma.

Comment: mano deu certo muito obrigado.

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar esta resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Comment: só não sei como que se faz isso. Sou novo aqui.

Comment: Esse link pode te ajudar em relação a isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/64969

Comment: Jefferson, fazer operador & para zerar o bit de sinal requer que o float seja movido do registrador float para a memória ou registrador inteiro para aplicar a operação, correto? Pelo que testei, fazer esse tipo de coisa tira desempenho. É melhor usar a função "abs" em sua versão intrínseca, dependendo até aplica o operador & da tecnologia SSE.

Comment: @RHERWOLF eu tentei sem usar `abs` intrínseca. Parecia que a intenção era elaborar todas as operações relativas ao cálculo das raízes. Mas essa parte do `&` precisar primeiro ir para um registrador de inteiro via memória foi ignorância minha, pensei que dava para fazer diretamente via registrador `float`. Obrigado por me mostrar errado =)