# Equação de matemática financeira em Java

Tags: java, matemática

Como posso codificar essa equação em Java?

```
750=(1-(1+j)^(-10))/j*86
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que seria codificar? Resolver a equação?

Comment: Resolver a equação em forma de código

Comment: Queres achar o valor de `j`?

Comment: Sim pretendo encontrar o valor de j

Comment: Posso fornecer uma aproximação numérica, não conheço solução exata para equações desse tipo. Vou postar em breve

Comment: Apesar de não ser o que busco, é sempre bom aprender algo novo. Manda pra mim se puder por e-mail ou aqui mesmo >> weriky.alphazer0@gmail.com

Comment: Vou postar como resposta, interessa aqui neste site ajudar a comunidade criando uma base de conhecimento do que simplesmente tirar uma dúvida e essa resposta ficar perdida

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Isso daí é uma fórmula de matemática financeira. Implementei em javascript uma bem parecida no semestre passado da minha pós. Vou ver se a encontro.

Comment: Ajudaria muito, obrigado!

Comment: 750=((1-(1+j)^(-10))/j*)86

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo? Não entendi seu comentário... foi para por em evidência que o 86 multiplica a divisão como um todo e não apenas o denominador?

Comment: para não parecer que seja o j multiplicado por 86 e sim tudo que está entre parenteses que é multiplicado por 86.

Comment: para não parecer que seja o j multiplicado por 86 e sim tudo que está entre parenteses que é multiplicado por 86.  Alias eu tb errei na colocação do ultimp parentesis o correto é 750=((1-(1+j)^(-10))/j)*86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse daqui realiza o cálculo usando o [**método da bissecção**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_da_bisse%C3%A7%C3%A3o), procurando o `j` no intervalo de 10<sup>−5</sup> até 1. Ele trabalha com `BigDecimal`s arredondando divisões com 21 casas decimais e trabalhando com uma margem de erro de 10<sup>−5</sup> no valor bruto do `q0` encontrado para aceitar a solução.

Eis o código:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

class Calculo {

    private static final BigDecimal CEM = new BigDecimal(100);
    private static final BigDecimal DOIS = new BigDecimal(2);

    private static final int PRECISAO_CALCULO = 21;
    private static final int PRECISAO_FINAL = 5;

    private static final BigDecimal DELTA =
            BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.TEN.pow(PRECISAO_FINAL));

    private static final BigDecimal financiamento(int n, BigDecimal j, BigDecimal p) {
        BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.ONE.add(j).pow(n);

        BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(
                a,
                PRECISAO_CALCULO,
                RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

        return BigDecimal.ONE
                .subtract(b)
                .multiply(p)
                .divide(j, PRECISAO_CALCULO, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    }

    private static final BigDecimal taxaFinanciamento(
            BigDecimal q0,
            int n,
            BigDecimal p)
    {
        BigDecimal j1 = DELTA;
        BigDecimal j2 = BigDecimal.ONE;
        BigDecimal q1 = financiamento(n, j1, p);
        BigDecimal q2 = financiamento(n, j2, p);
        BigDecimal m1 = q1.subtract(q0);
        BigDecimal m2 = q2.subtract(q0);
        if (m1.abs().compareTo(DELTA) <= 0) return j1;
        if (m2.abs().compareTo(DELTA) <= 0) return j2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            if (m1.signum() == m2.signum()) {
                throw new ArithmeticException("Fora do intervalo"
                        + ": q1=[" + q1 + "], j1=[" + j1 + "], m1=[" + m1 + "]"
                        + ", q2=[" + q2 + "], j2=[" + j2 + "], m2=[" + m2 + "]"
                        + ", i=" + i);
            }
            BigDecimal j3 = j1.add(j2).divide(DOIS);
            BigDecimal q3 = financiamento(n, j3, p);
            BigDecimal m3 = q3.subtract(q0);
            if (m3.abs().compareTo(DELTA) <= 0) return j3;
            if (m3.signum() == m1.signum()) {
                q1 = q3;
                j1 = j3;
            } else {
                q2 = q3;
                j2 = j3;
            }
        }
        throw new ArithmeticException("Não convergiu"
                + ": q1=[" + q1 + "], j1=[" + j1 + "], m1=[" + m1 + "]"
                + ", q2=[" + q2 + "], j2=[" + j2 + "], m2=[" + m2 + "]");
    }

    private static void teste(int q0, int p, int n) {
        BigDecimal bdq0Ideal = new BigDecimal(q0);
        BigDecimal bdp = new BigDecimal(p);
        BigDecimal j = taxaFinanciamento(bdq0Ideal, n, bdp);
        BigDecimal bdq0Obtido = financiamento(n, j, bdp);
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("q0-ideal=[" + bdq0Ideal + "]");
        System.out.println("p=[" + bdp + "]");
        System.out.println("j=[" + j + "]");
        System.out.println("q0-obtido=[" + bdq0Obtido + "]");
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        teste(750, 86, 10);
        teste(750, 85, 10);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
----------
q0-ideal=[750]
p=[86]
j=[0.025690244208984076976776123046875]
q0-obtido=[749.999997639096753068406]
----------

----------
q0-ideal=[750]
p=[85]
j=[0.023429261477030813694000244140625]
q0-obtido=[749.999996056141438963093]
----------
```

Esta saída significa que:

- Para um valor de ***p = 86*** e um ***q<sub>0</sub>*** desejado de ***750***, foi calculado que um valor ***j = 2,5690244...%*** produz um ***q<sub>0</sub> = 749,99999763...***
- Para um valor de ***p = 85*** e um ***q<sub>0</sub>*** desejado de ***750***, foi calculado que um valor ***j = 2,3429261...%*** produz um ***q<sub>0</sub> = 749,99999605...***

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/H5MUsP)

Comment: Pelo que acabei de ler sobre esse método, ele é muito mais adequado ao caso. No método dos trapézios, a possibilidade dele divergir é muito maior

Comment: O que seria o erro de não convergiu? Percebi que se coloco o valor da parcela em 85 ele retorna este erro                                                                   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Não convergiu: 749.92995258177 0.0234472656267621283632252016104757785797119140625 749.92995258175 0.0234472656267630165327631175387068651616573333740234375

Comment: @WerikyAlphazero Isso significava que após 50 tentativas, ele desistiu e não conseguiu encontrar a solução, mostrando o valor mais perto que ele atingiu. Entretanto, revisei e editei o código e corrigi esse erro. Agora ele consegue resolver este caso.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 5):

Estou utilizando o [método dos trapézios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) para resolver essa equação. Esse método também atende ao nome "método das secantes".

O método dos trapézios se aproxima muito ao do [Algoritmo de Newton-Raphson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237195/64969), mas no lugar de usar a derivada usa a diferença entre dois pontos dados para buscar o próximo ponto de tentativa. Não são todas as funções que se adequam ao uso desse método para encontrar suas raízes. Essa sua equação, por exemplo, não é.

Método de Newton-Raphson:

[image: Método de Newton-Raphson]

> ["Animation of Newton's method"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#/media/File:NewtonIteration_Ani.gif) por Ralf Pfeifer é licenciado sob [CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Método dos trapézios:

[image: Método dos trapézios]

> ["Illustration of the secant method"](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Secant_method.svg) de Jitse Niesen, domínio público.

Joguei no [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)+%3D+86*(1+-++(1+%2B+x)%5E-10)+%2F+x+-+750) para saber uma das raízes reais e ver se consigo me aproximar.

```
import java.util.function.DoubleUnaryOperator;

public class ResolucaoTrapezio {
    private Double raiz;
    private Integer iteracoesTotal;
    private Double errRaiz;

    public boolean achouRaiz() {
        return raiz != null;
    }

    public Double getRaiz() {
        return raiz;
    }

    public Double getErrRaiz() {
        return errRaiz;
    }

    public Integer getIteracoesTotal() {
        return iteracoesTotal;
    }

    public ResolucaoTrapezio(DoubleUnaryOperator func, double x0, double x1, double err, int iteracoes) {
        achaRaiz(func, x0, x1, err, iteracoes);
    }

    public void achaRaiz(DoubleUnaryOperator func, double x0, double x1, double err, int iteracoes) {
        double y0, y1;

        y0 = func.applyAsDouble(x0);
        if (diffErrAceitavel(y0, err)) {
            iteracoesTotal = 0;
            raiz = x0;
            errRaiz = -y0;
            return;
        }

        for (int it = 0; it < iteracoes; it++) {
            y1 = func.applyAsDouble(x1);

            if (diffErrAceitavel(y1, err)) {
                iteracoesTotal = it + 1;
                raiz = x1;
                errRaiz = -y1;
                return;
            }

            // entrou em laço infinito =(
            if (y1 == y0) {
                break;
            }

            // próximo passo, achando o próximo x
            double x2 = x0 - y0*(x1 - x0)/(y1 - y0);

            // atualizando: x_{i} <-- x_{i-1}
            x0 = x1;
            x1 = x2;

            // atualizando: y0 recebe o último y encontrado
            y0 = y1;
        }
        iteracoesTotal = null;
        raiz = null;
        errRaiz = null;
        return;
    }

    private static boolean diffErrAceitavel(double y0, double err) {
        return Math.abs(y0) < err;
    }
}
```

Esse objeto, a partir do construtor, tenta achar a resposta usando o método dos trapézios. Ele tem algumas limitações propositais para evitar processamento divergente, como detecção de retângulo e quantidade de iterações. Também considera que a raiz é um número próximo o suficiente de zero de acordo com um erro passado. Estou usando 7 casas decimais de precisão, então o erro é garantido ser menor do que `0.0000001`.

Se não for possível encontrar a raiz, o valor de `getRaiz()` e de `getErrRaiz()` serão nulos. Eu sempre estou guardando quantas iterações usei para chegar na conclusão de que cheguei na raiz ou divergi no `getIteracoesTotal()`.

Para a sua função, usei a seguinte fórmula:

```
(j) -> {
    double q0 = 750;
    double n = 10;
    double p = 86;

    return p*(1 -  Math.pow(1 + j, -n)) / j - q0;
}
```

Se quiser achar o valor de outra variável, é só por a variável como parâmetro e fixar o valor de `j`. Por exemplo hipotético:

```
(n) -> {
    double q0 = 750;
    double p = 86;
    double j = 0.0256902;

    return p*(1 -  Math.pow(1 + j, -n)) / j - q0;
}
```

Um exemplo de chamada desse objeto é o seguinte:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResolucaoTrapezio resTrap = new ResolucaoTrapezio((j) -> {
            double q0 = 750;
            double n = 10;
            double p = 86;

            return p*(1 -  Math.pow(1 + j, -n)) / j - q0;
        }, -1.8, -1.5, 0.00000001, 1000);

        System.out.println("resolução da equação: " + resTrap.getRaiz() + ", nessa quantidade de iterações: " + resTrap.getIteracoesTotal() + " (erro " + resTrap.getErrRaiz() + ")");
    }
```

A saída obtida foi:

> ```
> resolução da equação: -1.756371998522421, nessa quantidade de iterações: 10 (erro -3.410605131648481E-13)
> ```

Aqui, no método dos trapézios achar os primeiros dois valores bons é fundamental. O [@VictorStafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132/victor-stafusa) sugeriu que eu devesse começar com 0.25 e 0.5.

Testando a sugestão do @VictorStafusa:

> ```
> resolução da equação: null, nessa quantidade de iterações: 1000 (erro null)
> ```

Bem, divergiu...

Então, podemos tentar adivinhar quais são os pontos iniciais para essa função... Comecemos de `0.001` até `0.9` como `x0`, passo de `0.0001`. Façamos com que `x1` difira de `x0` um `delta` entre `0.00001` a `0.5` de `x0` variando a cada passo `0.00001`.

Eu consigo fazer isso através do seguinte `for`:

```java
for (double x0 = 0.001; x0 <= 0.9; x0 += 0.0001) {
    for (double delta = 0.0001; delta <= 0.5; delta += 0.0001) {
        double x1 = x0 + delta;
        // processamento desejado aqui
    }
}
```

Tentando achar a raiz...

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DoubleUnaryOperator f = (j) -> {
        double q0 = 750;
        double n = 10;
        double p = 86;

        return p*(1 -  Math.pow(1 + j, -n)) / j - q0;
    };

    int divergencias = 0;
    int convergencias = 0;
    int totalIteracoesAcc = 0;
    for (double x0 = 0.001; x0 <= 0.9; x0 += 0.0001) {
        for (double delta = 0.0001; delta <= 0.5; delta += 0.0001) {
            double x1 = x0 + delta;

            ResolucaoTrapezio resTrap = new ResolucaoTrapezio(f, x0, x1, 0.00000001, 1000);

            totalIteracoesAcc += resTrap.getIteracoesTotal();

            if (resTrap.achouRaiz()) {
                if (convergencias < 10) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("ACHOU RAIZ... parâmetros: x0 = %f x1 = %f; raiz = %f (err = %f); iterações %d", x0, x1, resTrap.getRaiz(), resTrap.getErrRaiz(), resTrap.getIteracoesTotal()));
                }
                convergencias++;
            } else {
                if (divergencias < 10) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("não achou raiz... parâmetros: x0 = %f x1 = %f; iterações %d", x0, x1, resTrap.getIteracoesTotal()));
                }
                divergencias++;
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("Já rodamos %d iterações ao todo; %d convergências, %d divergências", totalIteracoesAcc, convergencias, divergencias));
        }
    }
}
```

Saída:

> ```
> ACHOU RAIZ... parâmetros: x0 = 0,001000 x1 = 0,001100; raiz = 0,025690 (err = -0,000000); iterações 6
> Já rodamos 6 iterações ao todo; 1 convergências, 0 divergências
> ACHOU RAIZ... parâmetros: x0 = 0,001000 x1 = 0,001200; raiz = 0,025690 (err = -0,000000); iterações 6
> Já rodamos 12 iterações ao todo; 2 convergências, 0 divergências
> ACHOU RAIZ... parâmetros: x0 = 0,001000 x1 = 0,001300; raiz = 0,025690 (err = -0,000000); iterações 6
> Já rodamos 18 iterações ao todo; 3 convergências, 0 divergências
> [... omitido por questão de porque sim ...]
> ```

Bem, achamos a raiz. Feliz? Eu estou =D

Por curiosidade, se o algoritmo rodasse para todas as combinações possíveis de `x0` e `x1`, o tempo que ele levaria...

> ```
> Rodamos ao todo -1825970073 iterações ao todo; 12818639 convergências, 32136361 divergências
> Tempo total: 519060 ms
> ```

Bem, estourou o inteiro, vou colocar um `long` que deve aguentar. Também vou por `long` para o número de convergências e divergências por via das dúvidas...

Novo resultado, agora sem *overflow* de inteiros:

> ```
> Rodamos ao todo 32533768295 iterações ao todo; 12818639 convergências, 32136361 divergências
> Tempo total: 492871 ms
> ```

---

## Ressalva quanto a tipagem

Eu sou um dos maiores defensores de que, quando você está lidando com matemática financeira e dinheiro, você deveria usar `BigDecimal`.

Entretanto, a abordagem de resoluçao deste problema foi via métodos numéricos. É tanto que eu posso não encontrar a raiz real, mas eu encontrei um valor que está a um erro máximo de `1e-7` de `0`. Os cálculos e resultados desses métodos numéricos trazem consigo um erro intrínseco que não cabe ao tipo exato `BigDecimal`, mas sim cabe ao tipo científico `double`.

Leia mais:

- [Float, Double e Decimal. Qual a forma correta de usá-los?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/64969)
- [Resposta minha da pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219465/64969)

Comment: Na verdade, eu havia sugerido 0.25 e 0.5.

Comment: Perdão, vou atualizar agora... descobri que o número de iterações acima ultrapassa o  `int` (acabou de terminar a execução)

Comment: Divergiu =P Nem vou precisar alterar muito a minha resposta

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento