# por que essa equação não compila?

Tags: python

```
import math

def f(x):
    eq = (4-8*x)*math.cosh(2x)
    return eq

a= 0
b= 1
erro = math.pow(10,-3)

if f(a)*f(b) < 0:
    x=(a+b)/2
    while (math.fabs(f(x)) > erro):
        x=(a+b)/2
        if f(a)*f(x)<0:
            b=x
            g = (b - a)
        else:
            a=x

            print("raiz: ",a , "valor da função: ", f(x), "erro aproximado", (b-a))
else:
    print("não há raizes")
```

Erro:

> ```
> File "C:/Users/Giovane/Desktop/2018.2/calculo numerico/bisseccao.py", line 4
>    eq = (4-8*x)*math.cosh(2x)
>                            ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@GiovaneRamos, seu código possui alguns problemas:
1. Como o pessoal já mencionou, você precisa atualizar em `f(x)` a multiplicação para `math.cosh(2*x)` 
2. Ao analisar seu código, vejo que existe um erro de arquitetura, pois ao rodar com esses valores de `a` e `b`, ao calcular o primeiro `x`, o valor dele vai ser de 0.5, porém esse valor já é a raiz da equação `f(x)`, e como o output da função de `x` vai ser zero, o que é sempre menor do que o `erro`, e por isso não vai nem entrar no `while`, e portanto não vai imprimir nada (pois o `print` está dentro do `while`)
3. Usando o `print` final do seu `while`, pelo conceito que você está usando, da raiz ser o valor médio dentro do intervalo, então a raiz deveria ser `x` e não `a`, como você está imprimindo. 
4. O erro aproximado não seria `(b-a)`, mas `math.fabs(f(x))`

Portanto, a maneira de resolver de forma mais simples os pontos 2 e 3, seria trocar o `print` para dentro do `if`, e não do `while`, e assim garantir que ele sempre vai imprimir a raiz correta, que no caso é `x`, conforme abaixo:

```
if f(a)*f(b) < 0:
    x = (a + b)/2
    while (math.fabs(f(x)) > erro):
        x=(a+b)/2
        if f(a)*f(x)<0:
            b=x
            g = (b - a)
        else:
            a=x
        # Desconte a linha baixo caso queira acompanhar as iterações do algoritmo até chegar na raiz
        # print("x: ", x, "erro: ", math.fabs(f(x)))
    print("raiz: ", x , "valor da função: ", f(x), "erro aproximado", math.fabs(f(x)))
else:
    print("não há raizes")
```

Answer (score 5):

De acordo com o que você disponibilizou, o erro está acontecendo por causa do `math.cosh(2x)`. Em uma equação matemática "escrita", esse `2x` seria o equivalente a 2 vezes a variável *x*, ou, no caso, o parâmetro *x* da função. Entretanto, a linguagem Python, e acho que todas as outras linguagens de programação, não entendem da mesma forma, pois, nas linguagens de programação a operação de multiplicação tem que ser representada com o `*` (ex.: `2*2 == 4`, `4*4 == 16`, etc.).

Resumo: só substituir o `2x` por `2*x`, e esse erro não irá mais ocorrer.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: certo amigo, resolvi esse problema, agora compila mas o paycharm fica doido dizendo que não existe raiz na equação, mesmo com o intervalo correto, o programa funciona com qualquer polinômio de qualquer grau

Comment: @GiovaneRamos, você conseguiu a resposta ao seu problema específico, apresentado na pergunta. O algoritmo do cálculo das raízes a partir das bisseções estar errado é outro problema, que inclusive creio já ter uma resposta muito elegante sobre o assunto de um usuário chamado Victor Stafusa

Comment: Essa é a [resposta que mencionei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252395/64969)

Answer (score 4):

Boa noite Giovane, eu dei uma olhada no seu código, e o fato dele não compilar é realmente devido a um erro sintático existente no seu código.
O erro encontra-se na expressão **math.cosh(2x)**, ele ocorre devido ao fato de você estar passando o valor 2x como um valor único, porém o interpretador de um código não realiza operações de multiplicações dessa forma, para que as mesmas sejam executadas, é necessário a utilização do operador de multiplicação, o * (asterisco).

Logo, seu código deve estar somente com essa modificação, ficando da seguinte forma: **math.cosh(2 * x)**.

Como sua dúvida foi em Python, sugiro que da próxima vez, ponha seu código bem identado e na região de código do stack overflow, para facilitar o entendimento do problema.

Comment: certo amigo, resolvi esse problema, agora compila mas o paycharm fica doido dizendo que não existe raiz na equação, mesmo com o intervalo correto, o programa funciona com qualquer polinômio de qualquer grau